# How to get a specific class that is in a div

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm at the beginning with the Html Agility Pack library, I can't understand why if I only take the divs with the following code it works

```
Dim url As String = "https://example.com"
Dim web = New HtmlWeb()
Dim doc = web.Load(url)

For Each node As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div")

    Console.Write(node.InnerText)

Next
```

while if I want to find a class in a div like in the following code it gives me an error

```
Dim url As String = "https://example.com"
Dim web = New HtmlWeb()
Dim doc = web.Load(url)

For Each node As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='myclass']")

    Console.Write(node.InnerText)

Next
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is: System.NullReferenceException

Comment: You should be able to narrow down exactly which object is unexpectedly null. That's programming 101. Step through the code and check the values for each part of the expression on each line until you find it.